# Can i iterate over an image while ignoring black pixels?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image, superpixels

I have a segmented image using SLIC from scipy and for every superpixel i get an image where only that superpixel is colored and the rest of the image is black. I want to iterate ONLY on the colored pixels from that one superpixel.
I have tried using for loop like this:

```
for i in range(0,mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,mask.shape[1]):
            x,y,z = each_segment[i][j] #gets the pixel RGB value
            unique_pixel_array = [x,y,z] #creates a vector that holds those values for each pixel
            if (unique_pixel_array != [0,0,0]):
                print(unique_pixel_array)
```

This method is working however it is very inefficient considerin it is iterating over the entire image, and if i have a big image it will take a very long time to process for every superpixel.
Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

I will attach the whole code below , maybe you will get a better sense of the whole thing.

```
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("image.png")
segments = slic(img_as_float(img),n_segments= 7 ,slic_zero=True,sigma =5)
fig = plt.figure("Superpixels -- %d segments" % (22))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(img, segments))
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()

for (sp,segVal) in enumerate (np.unique(segments)):

    mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],dtype = "uint8")
    mask[segments == segVal] = 255
    each_segment = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

    for i in range(0,mask.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,mask.shape[1]):      
            x,y,z = each_segment[i][j]
            unique_pixel_array = [x,y,z]
            print(unique_pixel_array)



    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("Applied", cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You have an image, which you didn't share (?), and you have segmented it. You now want to iterate over the pixels but it is unclear to me what the expected result will be? All I understand is that it is too slow. What will the result be please? Will it be one output image per segment with the pixels in that segment showing and the rest black maybe? Or is the result some list of vectors of something else? Sorry for being dim. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, you got it right. I didnt add an image because that was not relevant. Any image would do just fine. The output is exactly as you said , the pixels in the segment are colored and the rest is black. and i want to be able to only iterate the colored ones. Sorry if i wasn't very clear.Thank you.

Comment: You want to *"iterate the over the coloured pixels"* to produce *what*?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have an expectation-maximization algorithm that i want to apply on each and every colored segment separately.

Comment: Surely you can just do `Y, X = np.where(mask==255)` and iterate over just those `Y`, `X` values?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for the idea , i'm gonna try implementing it now.